# Proving a sequence is measurable in (n-1)th sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory

Given $Z_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} E(X_k - X_{k-1}|F_{k-1})$ where $F_{k-1}$ denotes (k-1)th sigma algebra and $\left\{X_n\right\}$ is $F_n$-measurable. Prove that $\left\{Z_n\right\}$ is measurable in $F_{n-1}$

**My attempt:** I tried using induction. Start with $n=1$, we obviously have: $Z_1$ is measurable in $F_0$ (by property of conditional expectation). Now assume it's true up to $n=k$, we need to show it's true for $n=k+1$, which means we need to show: $Z_{n+1} = Z_n + E(X_{n+1} - X_{n}|F_{n})$ is $F_{n}$ measurable. I noticed that $Z_{n+1} - Z_n$ is $F_n$ measurable (again, by property of conditional expectation). But then I got stuck here:(

**My question:** Could someone help me complete the proof above? I think I would need to use the fact that $X_n$ is $F_n$ measurable, but I have not realized how to use this fact yet.

Comment: So... $Z_{n+1} - Z_n$ is $F_n$ measurable and $Z_n$ is $F_{n-1}$-measurable and $F_{n-1}\subseteq F_n$ and $Z_{n+1}=(Z_{n+1} - Z_n)+Z_n$, hence...

Comment: wait a minute. we are not given $F_{n-1}\subset F_n$?...main reason why I was pondering for a while

Comment: Yes we are. Check your notes.